# Create class dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I define and create instance of class dynamically like below:

```
var type = 'Animal';
window[type] = function() {};
var animal1 = new window[type]();
var animal2 = new Animal();
```

Then `animal1` will be shown in Chrome debugger as instance of `Object` (but with correct properties) while `animal2` will have type `window.Animal`.

When `Animal` is defined statically:

```
function Animal() {}
```

both objects are seen as instances of `Animal`.

How can I achieve this while defining functions dynamically (without using eval) ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. http://i.imgur.com/68DUI.png .. for me they're both shown as instances of `window.Animal`

Comment: My bad, I've oversimplified. Seems like you need to have the type name in variable to reproduce. Can you try again ?

Comment: Also cannot reproduce, after your update.  For me, both variables have type `window.(anonymous function)`.

Comment: I think this is an interesting phenomenon, but like Steve, I can't reproduce your first case. The second case (static vs dynamic *definitions*) I am seeing, and I think it's interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The cosmetics of what the Chrome console shows you seem to be determined by:

1. the `name` property of the constructor function, or
2. the variable name that the constructor function is *initially assigned* to (if `name` is not set).

**Case #1:**

```
var ClassA = function ClassB() {};
new ClassA();
// reports a `ClassB` object
```

The constructor function has its `name` property set to `ClassB`, so that's what Chrome reports. A function's `name` is only settable at definition time, so `function funcName(){}` sets the `name`, whereas `func=function(){}; f.name='funcName';` does not.

**Case 2:**

```
var ClassA = function() {};
ClassB = ClassA;
new ClassB();
// reports a `ClassA` object
```

The constructor was initially assigned to `ClassA`, so that name seems to be burned into the constructor function, even if it is used under another variable alias.  In fact, doing `delete window.ClassA` does not stop newly constructed objects from reporting themselves as ClassA objects:

```
var ClassA = function() {};
ClassB = ClassA;
delete window.ClassA;
new ClassB();
// still reports a `ClassA` object
// even though `ClassA` is no longer a defined variable name
```

This is what is happening in your "dynamically defined" case. The initial `window[type] = function() {};` line is permanently marking that constructor's resulting object to identify as type "`anonymous function that's a property of window`".

Note that these console cosmetics will not affect the functionality of your program, as all object/prototype functionality still works as expected.